# golang: Set type struct to nil

Tags: go

```
type Ptr struct {
    ID   *big.Int
    IpAddress string
    Port      string
}
var NewVar Ptr
```

After initializing the NewVar with values I then want to set NewVar to nil. How can I do this?

Comment: A struct value can't be nil. I think you really need to start off with the [docs](http://golang.org/doc/)

Comment: I think you're confusing a pointer to a stuct with the value itself. `nil` is not an allowed value for a struct. It is however, a common value for a pointer. If `NewVar` were declared as `var NewVar *Ptr` it could be set to `nil`. It could also be set to something like `&Ptr{}`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The [zero value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value) of a struct value is not nil

> Each element of such a [variable](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Variables) or value is set to the zero value for its type: `false` for booleans, `0` for integers, `0.0` for floats, `""` for strings, and **`nil` for pointers, functions, interfaces, slices, channels, and maps**.

In your case, this [variable declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Variable_declarations) `var NewVar Ptr` creates the  variable, binds corresponding identifier `Ptr` to it, and gives it a type and an initial value.

Comment: @EliMiller ID is declared as a *pointer* to big.Int, which means its zero value will be `nil`.